# .NET HttpListener Prefix issue with anything other than localhost

Tags: c#, http, httplistener

I'm trying to use C# and `HttpListener` with a prefix of anything other than localhost and it fails (i.e. if I give it `server1`, i.e.

`http://localhost:1234`  works, but

`http://server1:1234`  fails

The code is...

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
String prefix = @"http://server1:1234";
listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
listener.Start();
```

The failure occurs on `listener.Start()` with an exception of `Access is denied.`.

Comment: ancient question but shouldn't the prefix end with a forward slash /

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue once and i solved it by adding an URL reservation for the specified URL namespace for a user/users to the Network Shell (netsh). Here's an example on how to reserv an URL for every user, run this in the command prompt as an administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://server1:1234/ user=Everyone
```

Here's an example on how reserv an URL for one user, run this in the command prompt as an administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://server1:1234/ user=Steve
```

In this way you don't need to run the application as an administrator

Comment: What does this do actually ? `netsh http add urlacl url=http://server1:1234/ ` Is it like using hosts file ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, Network shell (`netsh`) is a command-line utility that allows you to configure and display the status of various network communications server roles and components. `http add urlacl url=http://server1:1234/` reserves the specified URL for non-administrator users and accounts. In this case `user=Everyone` for every account.

Answer (score 4):

Is your app running with elevated privilege?

Normal accounts cannot hook the Http pipeline without first making a reservation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa364673

It can be done programatically at install time. Let me know if this is of interest, and I'll dig out some code.

EDIT:

Actually, as I can't identify where the code came from at the moment, I can't post it here. There's a [codeplex project for doing this kind of thing](http://urlreservation.codeplex.com/) which is definitely worth picking apart.

/EDIT

Here's a way make the reservation on the command line:

http://www.casadehambone.com/HowToAddAURLACLAndAvoidAddressAccessDeniedExceptionInWindowsVista.aspx

Comment: Sub-question: Can one count on not having to make a reservation for `http://localhost:{port}/`?

On Win7, I'm able to listen on the port without reserving, but then I have installed a ton of stuff already and haven't tested on stock Windows 7. Also, wondering what the policy is on Windows Vista and Windows XP SP2. I'd be thrilled if localhost were a special case that I didn't have to worry about.