# Any small embeddable .Net web server suitable for service status pages?

Tags: c#, webserver

Is there a simple way, perhaps using the standard libraries, to serve a webpage from my windows service?

I'm not looking for anything fancy I'd just like to serve status/control pages for some of my windows services but don't want to rewrite them as web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) is your friend, although [making a reservation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564669/net-httplistener-prefix-issue-with-anything-other-than-localhost) in the HTTP pipeline for non-admin accounts (i.e. service accounts) is a bit of a pain. There's a [codeplex](http://urlreservation.codeplex.com/) project that you can hack into a custom action on your service installer.

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by "making a reservation in the HTTP pipeline"?

Comment: I added a link to an answer I gave a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

What about Cassini which used to come with the .NET development framework?

http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/cassini

Answer (score 0):

You could always check out the code for Cassini. It was written for .net 1.1, but I'm sure porting would be easy enough:
http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/cassini