# HTTPListener not working over network

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

I tried creating a simple HTTP server using System.Net.HTTPListener, but it doesn't receive connections from other computers in the network. Example code:

```
class HTTPServer
{
    private HttpListener listener;
    public HTTPServer() { }
    public bool Start()
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/");
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
        return true;
    }
    private static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
        Console.WriteLine("New request.");

        HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
        HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

        byte[] page = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test");

        response.ContentLength64 = page.Length;
        Stream output = response.OutputStream;
        output.Write(page, 0, page.Length);
        output.Close();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HTTPServer test = new HTTPServer();
        test.Start();
        while (true) ;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code, or is there another problem?

I've tried running the application with administrator privileges, but when I browse to the computer's IP address (i.e. 192.168.1.100) on another computer, I never receive the request. The server works fine if the request is sent from the same computer as where the application is running (using "localhost", "127.0.0.1" and "192.168.1.100"). Pinging works fine. I've also tried [nginx](http://nginx.org/), and that works perfectly over the network.

I'm using HTTPListener as a lightweight server to deliver a webpage with a Silverlight XAP file with some dynamic init params, clientaccesspolicy.xml and a simple mobile HTML page.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Firewall

Comment: You're right. That was pretty stupid of me. I assumed that since the application runs with administrator privileges that the firewall wasn't a problem. And weirdly, I never received a message from Windows Firewall whether to block or allow the program. Well, thank you.

Comment: This should win the shortest answer award or badge, nonetheless bang on target :)

Comment: Hah! I had to pad it with non-breaking spaces to get it up to length!

Comment: For some strange reason the same program was able to listen as a TCP server by opening a Socket instance, but failed for starting a HttpListener instance without admin rights.

Comment: @alex : Only administrator has privileges to hook the http pipeline without first getting a reservation. To do this as a standard user, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2564685/14357).

Comment: FFS. I came here for with the same problem and the firewall didn't even cross my mind. Jeez...

Comment: From my last 60-minute-problem-solving-experience, while the firewall automatically prompts you to allow remote connections for raw TcpListener or UDP connections, it fails to create a rule for HttpListener - go into your advanced Firewall settings and allow the port manually (as TCP)! Then check your router for forwarding it and https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ if it is really open.

Answer (score 6):

I also thought first of the Firewall. However the problem where my endpoints:

From a tutorial I had a code like the following

```
String[] endpoints = new String[] {
    "http://localhost:8080/do_something/",
    // ...
};
```

This code only works locally and only if you use localhost. To be able to use the IP, I changed it to

```
String[] endpoints = new String[] {
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080/do_something/",
    // ...
};
```

This time the request by ip adress worked, but the server did not respond to remote requests from another ip. What got me working for me was to use a star (*) instead of localhost and 127.0.0.1, so the following code:

```
String[] endpoints = new String[] {
    "http://*:8080/do_something/",
    // ...
};
```

Just leaving this here if somebody stumbles upon this post as I did.

Comment: Unfortunately the last part does not works for me. When I try to access server via local IP, I get "Unable to connect" (both from same machine and other machines in LAN).

Comment: Yes, I had to add all three of the those endpoints (localhost, 127.0.0.1 and *) as well as allow the application through the Windows Defender Firewall before HttpListener could see the connection.

Comment: @DrMcCleod that last one worked for me (adding all the 3)

Comment: To those reading this, remember that using http://*:8080 can be a security issue.