# UnableToStartHostException for any hostname except localhost

Tags: grapevine

Using Grapevine if I change the host to anything except "localhost" (or equivalent, 127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0) I will receive the following message:

```
Exception thrown: 'Grapevine.Exceptions.Server.UnableToStartHostException' in Grapevine.dll
```

I have tried: "*", "+" and an explicitly configured hostname (ie. "me.example.com").

There is no reason that this should fail at all, there is no other program or service using the hostname or port specified on any of the computers on this network, the ports are appropriately forwarded on both my router and firewall (even disabled the firewall and opened all ports temporarily to test).

Comment: Keep in mind that Grapevine is using HttpListener under the hood. Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19077666/1102764

Answer (score 0):

Grapevine is using `HttpListener` under the hood. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564669/net-httplistener-prefix-issue-with-anything-other-than-localhost/19077666#19077666) to a similar question will likely solve your issue.