# unable to connect to restful api hosted in docker container

Tags: c#, rest, docker, docker-compose, restsharp

I am facing an issue with my project i've built an api project and put it into a docker container.

I can reach the container via the web just fine using local host inside a browser, but when trying to consume it through code via restsharp, httpclient i get connection refused.

I tried local host, the direct 172 address assigned and even exposed a port pointed to 127.0.0.1 per other directions i've read.

I am at a lost of next steps because i can not seem to get this to work in any way

here is my simple code i set up:

api call

```
[Route("Internal/Email")]
    public class EmailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("Get")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<string> Get()
        {
            return "email got";
        }
    }
```

consumer call:

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private ServiceUrlConstants _serviceUrlConstants = new ServiceUrlConstants();
        private string _serviceUrl;
public IActionResult GetEmail()
        {
            try
            {
                _serviceUrl = _serviceUrlConstants.InternalServiceUrl;
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync(_serviceUrl + "Internal/Email/Get");
                var content = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                httpClient.Dispose();
                //client = new RestClient(_serviceUrl + "Internal/Email/Get");
                //var response = client.Execute(request);
                //var content = response.Content;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
}
```

Docker configuration (auto built by visual studio except third port exposure)

```
internalapiservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44310
    ports:
      - "17399:80"
      - "44310:443"
      - "127.0.0.1:45310:45310"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
```

Comment: Docker Toolbox, Docker Machine, or Docker for Windows?  What's `_serviceUrl` in your code?  (Better to make it configurable, say via an environment variable, then putting it in a "constants" class.)  Where are you running the client?

Comment: @DavidMaze i am running docker on windows using linux containers, the url is just a class right now with a conditional for debug, as the project progresses it will move into a config file.

that url is pointed to https://127.0.0.1:45310

i am running the client on the same machine as the debug session.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your ports and connections are fine. I do not think that this is a network problem, but a problem with the environment variables.

Try:
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost;http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

I don't think external connections are allowed by default. You could try adding a URL reservation as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564669/net-httplistener-prefix-issue-with-anything-other-than-localhost). Maybe something like:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:44310/ user=everyone
```

(It looks like you are mapping container port 443 to 44310 on your machine..?)